# Trying to make a action get called upon once every 5 seconds

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to make a class called timer. The timer class is supposed to be called upon when my character enters the enemy's area. And the timer class is supposed to remove the characters health by 10-health points every 5 seconds. Ive tried multiple different timers but i cant seem to get any of them right. When i tried it removed health but it didn't do it only once, it kept repeating it until the health bar was out of the screen. here is my code:

```
class Timer {
    g = new gubbe();
    gubbe g;
    Timer timer = new Timer(3000, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            g.RemoveHealth();
        }
    });
    timer.setRepeats(false); 
    timer.start();
 }
```

That is what I've come up with so far.
If any more code is needed just ask.

Comment: Does this code compile on your machine ? You are initializing `g` before declaring it.

Comment: Don’t name your own class `Timer` while importing a Java SE class named Timer (specifically javax.swing.Timer).  Choose a different name, like `HealthReducer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a class which you can use to time your events:

```
class Delay {
  protected int limit;

  public Delay() {limit = millis();}
  public Delay (int l) {
    limit = millis() + l;
  }

  public boolean expired () {
    if (millis() > limit) { return true; }

    return false;
  }
}
```

To check on something every 5 seconds, you would have to initialize it like this:

```
Delay _delay;

void setup() {
  _delay = new Delay(5000);
}

void draw() {
  if (_delay.expired()) {
    //do something
    _delay = new Delay(5000);
  }
}
```

The 5000 is in milliseconds, so it means 5 seconds. If you want to check for a 1 second delay, it would be 1000 instead. We re-initialize it when the delay is finished so it triggers again in 5 more seconds.

Have fun!

Comment: I tried putting the code you suggested in my project. There is one problem tho. I got a error message ive never seen before. it reads: duplicate field programmering_av_spel_karakt_r._delay. were the first part is the name of my project.

Comment: never mind sry. Figured it out. i had Delay _delay; in my other projekt to, which interfeared.

Comment: It's nice to see someone figure out this kind of issue by himself. Glad I helped!